# Cryptic Family Reunion: An Unexpected Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". **NOTE:** Unlike many previous puzzles in this genre, clues are NOT sorted alphabetically; however, lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Sister running nude to stream flowing around Hilton Head (9)
2. Dad's shock troop, quartered out north, found rebels (9)
3. Nephew and Mark Rogers, embracing sexuality at last (10)
4. Son comes from Bismarck up into Canadian border (6)
5. Activity like bridge, for example, taken up with Grandma (6)
6. South Korean manufacturer invested in South African uncle (6)
7. Grandpa's car overturned crossing decrepit bridge over train the wrong way (11)
8. Mom to serve pork without fanfare (4)
9. Brother's place to have lunch: lively swing with no whiskey limit (9)
10. Brother's place to have lunch: lively swing with no whiskey limit (7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answers to these are all:

> The **surnames of [hobbits](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Category:Hobbit_Families)** in the JRR Tolkien book '*The Hobbit*'. The first movie in the trilogy based on the book was suffixed with 'An **Unexpected** Journey', hence the title.

Solutions:

> 1. Sister running **nude** to **[stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rill)** flowing around **H**ilton Head (9) **UNDERHILL** = NUDE* + R(H)ILL
>
>  2. Dad's shock **troop**, quartered out **n**orth, **found** rebels (9) **PROUDFOOT** = TROOP* + FOUND* - N(orth)
>
>  3. Nephew and **Mark [Rogers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers)**, embracing sexualit**y** at last (10) **BRANDYBUCK** = BRAND + (sexualit)Y + BUCK (Rogers)
>
>  4. Son comes from **[Bismarck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_von_Bismarck)** up into **C**anadia**n** border (6) **COTTON** = C(OTTO)N
>
>  5. Activity like **[bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge)**, **for example**, taken up with Grandma (6) **GAMGEE** = GAM(EG<)E
>
>  6. **[South Korean manufacturer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Corporation)** invested in **[South African](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boer)** uncle (6) **BOLGER** = BO(LG)ER
>
>  7. Grandpa's **car overturned** crossing **decrepit bridge** over **[train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevated_railway)** the wrong way (11) **BRACEGIRDLE** = CAR< in BRIDGE* + EL<
>
>  8. Mom **to** serve **pork** without [**fanfare**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_relations) (4) **TOOK** = TO + PORK - PR
>
>  9. Brother's place to have **[lunch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sack-lunch)**: **lively** swing with no whiske**y** limit (9) **SACKVILLE** = SACK (lunch) + LIVELY* - (whiske)Y
>
>  10. Brother's place to have **[lunch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sack-lunch)**: lively **swing** with no **w**hiskey limit (7) **BAGGINS** = BAG (lunch) + SWING* - W(hiskey)

Comment: Awesome work Stiv...you crushed it!